# コンストラクタの初期化リストのコーディングスタイル

Tags: c++

メンバ変数が多いと初期化リストを書く場合に改行して縦に書きたい場合があります。
その場合に初期化リストの書き方でどう書くのが良いか迷ったのでまとめてみました。
それぞれの書き方についてのメリット、デメリットや別の書き方があれば教えてください。

※主にVS2013, 2015を使っているでそれを元にした意見になっています。
※1タブ4スペースを前提に書いています。

### No.1

- コロンの位置が人によっては違和感を覚える？
- インデントがそろっているのでVisualStudioのコード整形がきく。

```
class test_class
{
    test_class():
        a(),
        b(),
        c()
    {}

    int a, b, c;
};
```

### No.2

- カンマが行のはじめに来ているのであまり見慣れない？
- インデントがそろっているのでVisualStudioのコード整形がきく。

```
class test_class
{
    test_class()
        : a()
        , b()
        , c()
    {}

    int a, b, c;
};
```

### No.3

- 1つ目以降の変数のインデントがずれているのでコード整形を使うとずれてしまう。

```
class test_class
{
    test_class()
        : a(),
          b(),
          c()
    {}

    int a, b, c;
};
```

Comment: 私が自分で書くときはNo.2です。他人がどう書くかはあまり気にしません。

Comment: 経験上、No.2が最もdiffにやさしいと思う。

Comment: これ、前から気になってたんですけど、初期化リストの最初だけコロンで、二つ目以降がカンマってのが、なんかやだ。全部カンマで書けたら良かったのに。

Comment: 私もNo.2ですね。いろいろ試行錯誤しましたが、修正・変更などが発生した際に、個人的に一番やりやすかったスタイルです。

Comment: ドレが見やすいかは人それぞれ異なり、コンパイル時には結局全て同じコードになります。そのため、どれが正解とはつけられない(主観的な答えしか集まらない)質問です。複数人で開発するのであればコーディング規約を制定するなどして統一すれば良いです。

Answer (score 2):

私は下記の記述が良いと考えています。

```
class test_class
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
};
```

：を使った初期化子は実行順序が見た目と異なる可能性があり、余計なバグを生む可能性があります。

```
class test_class
{
    // 問題なさそうに見えるがa以外不定値
    test_class():
        a(),
        b(a),
        c(b)
    {}

    // cの初期化、bの初期化、aの初期化の順番で初期化される
    int c, b, a;
};
```

また、メンバ変数が多い場合初期化忘れがあり得ますが、こちらの記述で全て初期化しておくというルールにしておけば初期化忘れはまず防げると思います。

もし、コンパイラファイアウォールや動的メモリ確保の問題でこの記述を使いたくなった場合でも

```
test_class()
{
    foo = new Foo();
    bar = new Bar(foo);
}

Foo *foo = nullptr;
Bar *bar = nullptr;
```

の様にコンストラクタ初期化子を使わない記述の方が分かりにくいバグを生みにくいと思います。

Comment: クラス内初期化子はC++11以降でしか使えませんし、参照やconstメンバーはメンバー初期化子並びでしか初期化できませんが、その場合はどうするのでしょうか？

Comment: 環境はVS2013, 2015という事でC++11に関しては概ね問題ないでしょう。
一般的に参照メンバは避けるべきです。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892133/should-i-prefer-pointers-or-references-in-member-data
constメンバはtemplateを使う事でクラスのimmutable性を伝搬する事ができます。std::arrayのサイズをtemplate引数で渡す事は初期化子で渡す事よりも安全性を高めます。